# Incomprehensible ESlint warning about self-closing HTML void element

Tags: vue.js, eslint, nuxt.js

In my Vue project I have the following element:

```
<img
  class="header__branding__logo"
  src="@/assets/img/logo_desktop.svg"
/>
```

It is self-closing. Yet, ESlint throws this warning:

```
Disallow self-closing on HTML void elements (<img/>)  vue/html-self-closing
```

Doesn't make any sense to me, am I missing something? What's the problem?

Comment: Change to: `<img class="header__branding__logo" src="@/assets/img/logo_desktop.svg">` and your linter will be happy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your linter is just following the coding style you have configured it to follow. Your HTML is not invalid (although the `/` is considered unnecessary), but you have your linter configured to disallow that `/` on self-closing HTML tags, so that is why it is bringing it to your attention with a warning.